# Is there a formal limit for Google AppScript call payload size

Tags: javascript

It appears that client side call from JavaScript code to
`google.script.run.testFunc(payload)` will silently fail when apyload size exceeds 60157 bytes.
For the purpose of test, server side App Script function is as following:

```
export const testFunc = (payload) => {
  console.log(payload.length);
};
```

I am curious if anybody else is also facing the same issue and if there is legitimate workaround.

There is no such limitation documented in [App Script Reference for script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Can you provide the sample script for correctly replicating your issue of `It appears that client side call from JavaScript code to google.script.run.testFunc(payload) will silently fail when apyload size exceeds 60157 bytes.`? Because I couldn't know the value of `payload`. I apologize for this.

Comment: The value of payload is just hardcoded string of specified size. 
e.g. this will work fine

`google.script.run.testFunc(new Array(60158).join( 'A' ));`

and this will fail
`google.script.run.testFunc(new Array(60159).join( 'A' ));`

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I tested `google.script.run.testFunc(new Array(60159).join( 'A' ))`, no error occurs. And also, even when I tested `google.script.run.testFunc(new Array(1000000).join( 'A' ))`, no error occurs. I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. By the way, can you provide the detail of `fail` you are thinking?

Comment: It appeared that I had call to google.script.host.close() after test func call, which resulted in cancelation of original google.script.run for cases whan payload size is over 60158 bytes. After I moved google.script.host.close() into withSuccessHandler(), everything works fine. Thanks.